# Middleman tag sort case insensitive

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, tags, middleman

In Middleman static site generator, sorting the `tags` array is case sensitive.  Capital letters are sorted before lower case, as in: "A, B, C, a, b, c" when using the code:

```
<% blog.tags.sort.each do |tag, articles| %>
<% end %>
```

It seems like I should be able to use Ruby's `sort_by(&:downcase)`, such as:

```
<% blog.tags.sort_by(&:downcase).each do |tag, articles| %>
<% end %>
```

But that gives error:

> NoMethodError
>
> undefined method `downcase' for #<Array:0x007fc4baac00b8>

How can I case insensitive sort the `tags` collection?

Comment: I think your `tags` must not be an array of strings

Comment: @maxple Middleman Blog module defines tags as: `@return [Array<String>] (never +nil+)`

Answer (score 1):

blog.tags is actually returning multiple ruby objects in an Array. So the error 
 undefined method "downcase' for Array:0x007fc4baac00b8 is because blog.tags   looks similar to something like below.

```
[
 #<Array:0x007f9a41300cb8 id: 5, name: "Ruby">,
 #<Array:0x007f9a41300cb8 id: 5, name: "Ruby">,
]
```

I am not positive you are using active records on the Tags but you could just order them in the Tags model class.

```
 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :order_by_name, -> { order('LOWER(name)') }
 end

 # erb 
 <% blog.tags.order_by_name.each do |tag, articles| %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sorts case insensitive: `sort{|a,b| a.to_s.downcase <=> b.to_s.downcase}`

Applied to the Middleman `Tag` class instance in the erb file as:

```
<% blog.tags.sort{|a,b| a.to_s.downcase <=> b.to_s.downcase}.each do |tag, articles| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is strictly equivalent to the OP's code `blog.tags.sort_by(&:downcase).each do |tag, articles|`. If the original doesn't work, this won't either.

Comment: `blog.tags` isn't an array of strings, and must contain at least one array as element. Hence the error.

Comment: @EricDuminil Middleman Blog module defines tags as: `@return [Array<String>] (never +nil+)`

Comment: @JasonSturges you can put a debugger call such as `byebug` into your code (even ERB templates) and inspect it / run tests at runtime.